# Transparent Material - so that you can't see what's next object through it - Similar with green screen

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, materials, transparency, shader-nodes

I am wonder if it possible in blender (cycles) to create an "fake" transparent material, so that **you can't see** what's next object through it **and what you will be see is only transparent (alpha channel)**, something similar with a green screen.
Here it is an example with what I am trying to say...

[image]

Comment: Hi :). This might be a good case for the [holdout shader](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/shader/holdout.html)

Answer (score 1):

By adding the Holdout shader will make things work
[image]

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, this is an appropriate solution. Just be aware that **everything** behind the holdout object will disappear and will be transparent there.